# How to modify a image contrast into modified auto contrst image in image processing?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The code for Auto contrst is below, How I change this code to modified auto contrast.

```
for i=1:r
 for j=1:c
    a = I(i,j);   // Original Image intensity value assign to a
    if a<alow
        a1=amin;
    elseif a>ahigh
        a1=amax;
    else
        a1 = amin +((a - alow) * ((amax - amin) / (ahigh - alow)));
    end       
    J(i,j) = a1;
 end
 end
```

Comment: SO is not for code review. please consider posting in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: SO is not for code review. please consider posting in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could you describe what kind of "Modified Contrast" are you trying to implement?

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you want to stretch the luminosity levels of the such that its minimum value will be mapped to 0 and its max to 255 (Pay attention that your 2 first `if` won't be used ever).

The code should be:

```
mInputImage = imread('SomeGrayScaleImage.png');
mInputImage = double(mInputImage) / 255;

inputImageMinVal = min(mInputImage(:));
inputImageMaxVal = max(mInputImage(:));

mOutputImage = (mInputImage - inputImageMinVal) / (inputImageMaxVal - inputImageMinVal);
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

here the auto contrast code.

you have to call this function with K=255 and your image

```
 function I=autoContrast(I,K)

if length(size(I))==3
    I=rgb2gray(I);
end

[r,c]=size(I);
amin=0;
amax=K-1;

alow=min(min(I));
ahigh=max(max(I));

for x=1:r
    for y=1:c
        a=I(x,y);

        a1=amin+(a-alow)*((amax-amin)/(ahigh-alow));

        I(x,y)=a1;

    end
end
```